# How can I match database records (e.g. names) with voice input from an Alexa Skill?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, voice-recognition

I'm building an Alexa skill, and I have a slot called 'Name' where I want to capture a name. I want to find in the database the matching name. But let's say that I have in the database a name "Alex Baumgartner". But Alexa returns in a slot "Alex Baugartner".

Obviously, it doesn't match exactly but it matches with 0.95 probability. How can I check this probability or in some way verify that the voice input matches with the database record?

Is there a service online, a tool or algorithm for checking the probability of matching words that I should use, or is there another approach?

Comment: I think that you are asking on the wrong site. You could ask the same question without involving Alexa. So, you might get more help on another SE site ...

Comment: On the other hand, voice activation is a fairly major topic for IoT. Not sure we can help, but I think it's on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an Alexa specific answer, but look into support for soundex and similar phonetic hashing systems in your platform and/or database. For example the MySQL database has a soundex() function that can be used for this. BMPM is another algorithm supported out of the box by Apache Solr/Lucene, along with a number of others.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/phonetic-matching.html